# Duplicar tabla Mysql con codigo sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy tratando de duplicar una tabla llamada personas con PHP,la tabla contiene 5 columnas al ejecutar este comando

```
CREATE TABLE mi_tabla SELECT * FROM personas
```

automaticamente se crea la tabla con su nombre nuevo y también se copian todo los registros de la tabla madre, pero la PRIMARY KEY no se crea, la tabla se crea sin llave primaria y sin AUTOINCREMENT.Lo deseo hacer en esa misma linea
Como podria añadir eso ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Y si lo hacés con LIKE en vez de SELECT?

```
CREATE TABLE mi_tabla LIKE personas;
```

Y luego:

```
INSERT INTO mi_tabla SELECT * FROM personas;
```

Crear una tabla desde el SELECT no te va a copiar la estructura de la tabla, solamente el contenido.
Probá usando el like y luego hacer un insert, a ver si así funciona.